# National Land Cover Dataset 2016 Land Cover Change Index Values Meaning

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, nlcd

After downloading and clipping the NLCD 2016 Land Cover Change Index raster and viewing it in ArcMap, the table of contents shows a legend with values 0-12. They are depicted in the following picture:

[image: NLCD Land Cover Change Index Values]

What are these specific values?

I am looking for either an explanation of what the values mean or a link to their description. I gathered the data from the following URL: https://www.mrlc.gov/data?f%5B0%5D=category%3Aland%20cover

The Multi-Resolution Land Characteristics Consortium (MRLCC) (where the data is from) does not seem to provide a description of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing, found your question, then pulled up the metadata:

> The NLCD 2016 Land Cover Change Index is a raster image with an
>   accompanying look-up table that describes the land cover change
>   represented by each index. Previous releases of NLCD land cover
>   covered one target year, and a land cover change index was compiled of
>   change from every class in the previous target year to every class in
>   the current one – for example from 2006 to 2011 or from 2001 to 2006.
>
> NLCD 2016 Land Cover spans not one but seven target years: 2001, 2003,
>   2006, 2008, 2011, 2013, and 2016. Rather than compiling six land cover
>   change index products (one for each pair of adjacent target years),
>   there is a single NLCD 2016 Land Cover Change Index product whose
>   pixel values indicate land cover changes that occurred at least once
>   between 2001 and 2016. Each assigned image value represents either “No
>   Change” (Index number 1) or one of the changes described below.
>
> Index number 2 identifies pixels that have changed from any land cover
>   class to Water, or from Water to any other land cover class, between
>   any two adjacent target years. Indices 5, 7, 8, 10, and 21 are similar
>   identifiers of change from or to a single land cover class.
>
> Index 3 identifies changes from any land cover class to any of the
>   four Urban land cover classes, or from any of those four classes to
>   any other land cover class, between any two adjacent target years.
>   Index 11 similarly identifies changes from or to any of the three
>   Forest classes.
>
> Index 4 narrowly identifies changes only between Herbaceous Wetland
>   and Woody Wetland. Similarly, Index 6 identifies changes only between
>   Cultivated Crops and Hay / Pasture.
>
> Index 9 meets a special requirement of shrubland research to
>   discriminate where change occurs on persistent shrublands verses
>   change on  transitional shrubland areas such as regenerating forests.
>
> Pixel /Index Value    Description 1   No Change 2 Change from or to Water 
>   3 Change from or to any of the four Urban classes (open space; low,
>   medium, and high intensity) 4 Change from Herbaceous Wetland to Woody
>   Wetland, or vice versa 5  Change from or to Herbaceous Wetland 6  Change
>   from Cultivated Crops to Hay / Pasture, or vice versa 7   Change from or
>   to Cultivated Crops 8 Change from or to Hay / Pasture 9   Persistent
>   Grassland and Shrubland change. This change index attempts to identify
>   changes to persistent Grassland and Shrubland areas, and to separate
>   them from transitional shrubland areas such as regenerating forests.
>   10    Change from or to Barren 11 Change from or to any of the three
>   Forest classes (Evergreen, Deciduous, and Mixed) 12   Change from or to
>   Woody Wetland
>
> Identifying the specific changes from one target year’s land cover
>   class to another, and the specific target years when the changes
>   occurred, both require analysis of the land cover data itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This seems to make sense to me. Was this available in the metadata from the original dataset? I clipped my dataset already to save storage space so I'm wondering if that's why I am unable to see it.

Comment: That must be, I found it in the metadata!