# Which year change does NLCD Land Cover Change Index show?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, land-cover, nlcd

After downloading the National Land Cover Dataset (NLCD) Land Cover Change Index from the Multi-Resolution Land Characteristics Consortium (MRLCC) website, it only contains one raster file. However, the website states that the data is from a series of years (2016,2013,2011,2008,2006,2004,2001).

Does that mean that this file indicates the total change from the year 2001 to 2016 or is there a way to view the change between each set of years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in a response to another question at the following link:
[National Land Cover Dataset 2016 Land Cover Change Index Values Meaning](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350212/national-land-cover-dataset-2016-land-cover-change-index-values-meaning)